# Can we track changes made via workbench?

Tags: reporting, workbench, logging, audit-fields, field-audit-trail

We are working on our audit readiness and are preparing to restrict connected app access to Workbench for all profiles, except System Admins for full use and our Analysts so that they may do queries.

The question has been posed whether updates/edits made in workbench are identifiable in audit logs - my review does not show that there is a way to identify in the logs when workbench was used. Is there a way to track/log what is changed in workbench?

Comment: What are your objectives for the audit, specifically?

Comment: Object is to identify whether updates have been made via the workbench vs. data loader, or manual entry (both of which we can track).